# How to properly clean carpet from Najasah?

Tags: fiqh, taharah

I have a nephew younger than two-year-old and a grandfather older than seventy five. It sometimes happens that they can't hold their bladder and dirty the carpet. It is not easy to roll the carpet each time and send to carpet cleaner.

I can't wash the carpet as easy as my clothes because of its bulky body. Then how can I properly clean the carpet from the Najasah? Is wiping with a sponge using detergent enough to make it Tahir? What if some water drops from the sponge to the carpet when I am cleaning the carpet? Do I have to clean the carpet from unseen dirt(dried urine) ?

Comment: what do you mean by unseen dirt?

Comment: I don't know the exact terms in English. I may not be able to explain perfectly. I meant dried urine by unseen dirt.

Comment: i agree that the question, as worded, is only tenuously on-topic.  the body of the question should be reworked to mention that it's asking about cleanliness in the sense of 'tahir(طاهر‎)/najis(نجس)', rather than in the sense of 'unsightly urine stain'.

Comment: It is impossible to be completely sure that the whole urine is removed. Any of the below given methods do not work for a carpet IMO. you must most probably send it to the cleaner and remove the carpet from your hose till the urinating problem is not solved. one suggestion from my side - why not make those two guys wear diapers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is there a necessity for a carpet first of all? Alhamdulillah, your home may look good even without it. At this point in time, rather than decorating your home, the carpet is making it unclean.

So best of all, hand-wash it at least thrice, dry it in the sun and keep it in the store room for future.

Comment: Is this your own opinion? And I don't think keeping the carpet in the cellar is a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

according to Jafari Fiqh, you can pour water over area and collect it with something like spoon and repeat this 3 times.

ref:

http://www.al-islam.org/laws/

http://makarem.ir/websites/english/estefta/

Comment: but it is dried urine. pouring water will just make the carpet absorb the water and not remove the urine.

Comment: @Ashu 3 times of the poured water and collecting water washes it out. it will be dissolved and absorbed in water. anyway this is what Jafari Fiqh says and is enough for carpet being clean Islamicly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the hanbali madhab

In their article (islamqa) they say that the

> "The scholars of the Permanent Committee (5/364) were asked: Many people use luxury carpets in their homes. If a child of any age, for example, urinates on the carpet, is it sufficient to pour water on it in order to cleanse it of the impurity, seeing that the carpet may be large and may be attached to the floor [fitted carpet], or there may be large pieces of furniture and beds on it, or not?
>
> They replied: If the one who has urinated on these carpets and the like is a [baby] boy who is not yet eating solid food, sprinkling water over the entire area affected by the impurity is sufficient to purify it, and it is not essential to squeeze it or wash it.
>
> But if the child is eating solid food, or is a girl, regardless of whether she is eating solid food or not, then it must be purified by washing. It is sufficient to pour water on the site of the impurity, and it is not essential to remove the carpet or squeeze it; this is like the way of removing impurity on the ground, because it is proven in as-Saheehayn from Anas (may Allah be pleased with him) that a Bedouin urinated in the mosque and the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) instructed that a bucket of water be poured over his urine. End quote."

The hadith above is in [bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:219) according to sunnah.com and it reads

> حَدَّثَنَا مُوسَى بْنُ إِسْمَاعِيلَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا هَمَّامٌ، أَخْبَرَنَا إِسْحَاقُ، عَنْ أَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ، أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم رَأَى أَعْرَابِيًّا يَبُولُ فِي الْمَسْجِدِ فَقَالَ ‏ "‏ دَعُوهُ ‏"‏‏.‏ حَتَّى إِذَا فَرَغَ دَعَا بِمَاءٍ فَصَبَّهُ عَلَيْهِ‏.‏
>
> Narrated Anas bin Malik: The Prophet (ﷺ) saw a Bedouin making water in the mosque and told the people not to disturb him. When he finished, the Prophet (ﷺ) asked for some water and poured it over (the urine).
>
> Reference  : Sahih al-Bukhari 219
> In-book reference    : Book 4, Hadith 85
> USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 1, Book 4, Hadith 218
> (deprecated numbering scheme)

There is also a narration by Abu Huraira:

> حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو الْيَمَانِ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا شُعَيْبٌ، عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي عُبَيْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عُتْبَةَ بْنِ مَسْعُودٍ، أَنَّ أَبَا هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَامَ أَعْرَابِيٌّ فَبَالَ فِي الْمَسْجِدِ فَتَنَاوَلَهُ النَّاسُ، فَقَالَ لَهُمُ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ دَعُوهُ وَهَرِيقُوا عَلَى بَوْلِهِ سَجْلاً مِنْ مَاءٍ، أَوْ ذَنُوبًا مِنْ مَاءٍ، فَإِنَّمَا بُعِثْتُمْ مُيَسِّرِينَ، وَلَمْ تُبْعَثُوا مُعَسِّرِينَ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira: A Bedouin stood up and started making water in the mosque. The people caught him but the Prophet (ﷺ) ordered them to leave him and to pour a bucket or a tumbler of water over the place where he had passed the urine. The Prophet (ﷺ) then said, "You have been sent to make things easy and not to make them difficult."
>
> Reference  : [Sahih al-Bukhari 220](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:220)
> In-book reference    : Book 4, Hadith 86
> USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 1, Book 4, Hadith 219
> (deprecated numbering scheme)

Im not one-hundred percent sure if sunnah.com is trustworthy in terms of ratings, and they give no ratings for the hadiths above anyways. Their citations should be trustworthy as well as the hadiths they post (in and of itself, not including the ratings)

But they have a hadith on their website classed as sahih and you guys can read it your self: https://sunnah.com/urn/1101740

Here is the islamqa article it essentially states for purifying something on a carpet one must pour water on it until there are no signs or traces of it (color, smell, etc.) but one should read the article for context:
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/213577/how-can-carpets-be-purified-and-what-is-the-ruling-if-any-impurity-has-dried-up-without-water-being-poured-on-it

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about islam. You should give the answer in your own words and mark quotation as such (I've done this in this post). Referring to sunnah.com is enough hadith # are as you see irrelevant as no original book included these numbers or counts. For further information take the [tour] and check our [help].