# How to purify a carpet if I don't remember where the impurity is?

Tags: practical-islam, taharah, najis

Assalamualikum my question is that my carpet became impure of a specific impurity but after the impurity dried i don't remember which spot on the carpet is impure what do i have to do now?

Comment: I don't see any direct relevance for using the tags shari'a, Allah, fatwa nor fatwa-explanation. We don't know what you want to use this carpet for nor why you worry of having a dried najasah (whatever it might be) on it.

Comment: @Medi1Saif ♦ iam using this carpet for sitting and all the daily things we do in a room and i worry because i dont know ere the impurity is and if i walked on it with wet feet the impurity would yransfer

Comment: Why should a najasah transfer? I've asked you to show evidences for this claim in your first post on this topic and you failed to quote any.

Comment: @Medi1Saif♦https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/395362/method-of-purifying-a-carpet-or-seat-from-urine

Comment: but there is no stain

Comment: The characteristics for najasah that scholars have defined don't include stains (exclusively) as mentioned earlier some impurity may have others not there are three characteristics that might apply not all of them at once necessarily (you have senses use them). If you have doubt about the location wash the whole carpet.

Comment: the carpet is big it cant be washed

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is clear if there's a risk of impurity transfer because you use this carpet extensively then you should wash the carpet or replace it.
Note that a carpet you don't use in the means of a hypothetical impurity transfer doesn't need to be cleaned at all.

However imam as-Suyuti quoted in his book on fiqh rules al-Ashbaah wa an-Nadhaair [كتاب الأشباه والنظائر](https://al-maktaba.org/book/21719/429):

> قاعدة: " قال القمولي في الجواهر: النجس إذا لاقي شيئاً طاهراً وهما جافان لا ينجسه
> Rule: “Al-Qamuli said in Al-Jawaher: The impure (najis), if it met (touched/mixed with) something pure (tahir) and they are dry, it does not defile it.

This means a dried impurity doesn't transfer by default!

The main issue as said before is a Muslim must guard or seek tahrah (ritual purity) in order to be able to pray. So even if najasah was on your wet feet all you have to do in order to pray (in first place) is being sure you washed your feet  before starting the prayer.
As in the moment of prayer both you and the place you are praying on should be tahir (no more no less).
However washing off the najasah from the carpet would give you peace of mind for the future.

However the matter of impurity transfer in such cases is rather exaggerated because little najasah is equal to no najasah.

Further impurity has at least one of the three characteristics color, odor and taste. You may locate it by searching for them using your senses. But if you fail there's still the option of total certainty: washing the whole carpet.

See also [How to properly clean carpet from Najasah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/433/how-to-properly-clean-carpet-from-najasah)