# How to deal with impurity on clothes

Tags: halal-haram, taharah, clothing

A few months ago, I was indulged in Handpractice and don't wash the clothes after ejaculation (because I don't know the seriousness of this issue). Now half of my clothes has semen stains which is not removing after trying so hard. Is there any way to purify it? Else, What shall I do with those clothes? (I hid them in the basement)?

Comment: doesn't washing them remove it?.

Comment: I've tried even with soap and detergent but it didn't work

Comment: Put them in the washing machine and you're done!

Comment: See also [How and when is it allowed to treat najasah on items -without water-?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62386/how-and-when-is-it-allowed-to-treat-najasah-on-items-without-water) and [How to purify a carpet if I don't remember where the impurity is?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62384/how-to-purify-a-carpet-if-i-dont-remember-where-the-impurity-is)

Comment: Why people always recommending me the usage of water and remove the question and share another answer which again suggest water to remove Najasat. I've tried tge water but the stains doesn't remove