# How to wash najas clothes in washing machine?

Tags: sex, masturbation, clothing, najis, doubts

Recently I heard that when najasa (impurity[**ejaculation**]) has been touched with the clothes after **masturbation**, you can wash them by simply putting it in washing machine with high amount of water and detergent. Then after it wash, rinse and dry, **it becomes pure and you can use them again for praying**. I want to know that if it is true. If it is not true, then I would like to know how to wash Najis clothes in washing machine. I also read that after ejaculation **when the semen dries** you can do the same steps as I told earlier. So, all I want to know is **how to wash dried and wet Najis clothes which was mixed/touched with semen, is it okay to wash in a washing machine with high amount of water and detergent or it should be done in other ways**?

Comment: We already have a question covering the ways to clean najasah please check the site prior to posting duplicates. See [How and when is it allowed to treat najasah on items without water?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62386/how-and-when-is-it-allowed-to-treat-najasah-on-items-without-water)

Answer (score -1):

You dont need a washing machine. Just clean it with water the best way you can. Put water on the place and rubb the clothes together. And there are 3 kinds of of it:

1. Maniy is semen which is described as thick fluid that comes out with force and passion after which the erection subsides.
2. Madhi is a thin precoital fluid that comes out due to arousal after which the erection remains.
3. Wadi is a pre or post urinal emission.

Some Scholars say that maniy is not unpure because of this hadith:

From ‘Aa’ishah (may Allah be pleased with her) who said: I remember scratching it (maniy) from the garment of the Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon) thoroughly, then he prayed in it.

It is well-known that scratching is not sufficient to remove impurity, which indicates that it is pure. (Muslim)

Comment: what I am trying to say is...when my clothes were impure...I washed in a washing machine...and when washing was completed, there was no trace of the impurity...so is it now pure as there is no more trace on the cloth....and I'd like to ask one more question.. that is, do I have to wash the drum of the washing machine after I have washed the impure cloth because I heard that the washing machine becomes impure if I wash something impure in it but I am not sure if it is true or not.
Thank you very much for responding my question!!